# Retrieve and detect changes to metadata

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

I'm using jsforce to connect to salesforce account and detect changes to metadata.
Is there a way to detect changes to metadata other than using the SetupAuditTrail object?
If there is no other way, the only way i can think of is parsing the setupAuditTrail object and that feels to me unsafe.
Two problems with that approach is that the messages coming on the display section may change in time and cause a bug in my system and that I'm not sure I've covered all types of metadata changes messages.
Is there a way to get the format of those messages (on the display section) or a way to get the list of the messages that may be shown in the action section?

Thanks,

Dor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Salesforce DX [source:pull](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source) command. It pulls changes from the target org locally.

If you don't want to use the command directly you could pull apart the JavaScript source to find how they are tracking the Metadata changes that have occured in the target org.

---

There might also be some utility in the [Change Data Capture (Pilot)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_api_data_change_events.htm?edition=&impact=) schema tracking.